# issue in printing \G in mysql.?

Tags: mysql, shell

I am executing a Command

```
mysql -uroot -proot -Bse "select Concat('SHOW CREATE TABLE ',TABLE_SCHEMA ,'.',TABLE_NAME,'\\G') from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA Not IN('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema');"
```

I want output as

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.category\G
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.city\G
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.country\G
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.customer\G
```

But I am getting

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.categoryG
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.cityG
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.countryG
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.customerG
```

Why is this so? Where am I wrong?

**UPDATE**

If I write

```
mysql -uroot -proot -Bse "select Concat('SHOW CREATE TABLE ',TABLE_SCHEMA ,'.',TABLE_NAME,'\\\\G') from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA Not IN('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema');"
```

I get output as

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.category\\G
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.city\\G
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.country\\G
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.customer\\G
```

But I only want `\G`, not `\\G`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an additional level of escaping: `\\\\`

You give the query string th MySQL via a shell command line. The shell turns the `\\\\` (`\\` twice) into two `\`, i. e. `\\`. That is because it is enclosed in `"`s.

MySQL sees the `\\\\` as `\\` and, as it has its own escaping, uses it as `\`.

---

EDIT: I don't understand why, but this doesn't work with your query.

But by fiddling around with it, one wasily finds out that both `\\\\G` and `\\\G` would be the way to go.

Alas, the data is modified on output in the MySQL CLI client. As its output is escaped to allow for `\0`. `\t` etc. to be output, it as well has to escape the `\` on output.

With the CLI parameter `-r` or `--raw`, you can disable that behaviour. (Your `s` option, however, should be redundant, as it is included in `B`.) And maybe `N` wouldbe useful, disabling the headers.

So use `-Bre` or `-NBre` instead of `-Bse` and you are perfectly fine with `\\\\G`.

Comment: Didn't I write it above? `\\\\ `. I.e., `\\\\G`.

Comment: @glglgl: If i wrire '\\\G' i still get the output as in my UPDATE part of question.

Comment: @AbdulManaf Updated again. Note the `r` option turning on raw output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` to fix this.

Here is what i did.

1. Change the ending string of CONCAT call from `\\G` to `\\\\G`.
2. Piped the output to `sed -s 's/\\\\G/\\G/'` to replace it.

Here is the query.

```
mysql -uroot -proot -Bse "select Concat('SHOW CREATE TABLE ',TABLE_SCHEMA ,'.',TABLE_NAME,'\\\\G') from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA Not IN('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema')" | sed -s 's/\\\\G/\\G/'
```

Comment: `-r` option is more straightforward, IMO.